# How to Find out Average Skin color of face from Face Detection part in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity

I need to get Average color  of the skin from the face detected part ... How do i find the Average skin color?

Now i get the Average skin color by RGB pixel value ... Still i not matching with the source image.i got the Average color of face  is totally different.

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    int redBucket = 0;
    int greenBucket = 0;
    int blueBucket = 0;
    long pixelCount = 0;
    canvas.drawBitmap(myBitmap, 0, 0, null);

    Paint myPaint = new Paint();
    myPaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    myPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    myPaint.setStrokeWidth(3);

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfFaceDetected; i++) {
        Face face = myFace[i];
        PointF myMidPoint = new PointF();
        face.getMidPoint(myMidPoint);
        myEyesDistance = face.eyesDistance(); 
        canvas.drawRect((int) (myMidPoint.x - myEyesDistance * 2),
        (int) (myMidPoint.y - myEyesDistance * 2),
        (int) (myMidPoint.x + myEyesDistance * 2),
        (int) (myMidPoint.y + myEyesDistance * 2), myPaint);

        resizedbitmap=Bitmap.createBitmap(myBitmap,(int) (myMidPoint.x - (myEyesDistance)*2),  
        (int) (myMidPoint.y - (myEyesDistance)*2),  
        (int) (myEyesDistance*4),  
        (int) (myEyesDistance*4));       

        for (int y = 0; y < resizedbitmap.getHeight(); y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x <resizedbitmap.getWidth();x++) {                         
                int pixel = resizedbitmap.getPixel(x,y);                
                pixelCount++;
                redBucket += Color.red(pixel);
                greenBucket += Color.green(pixel);
                blueBucket += Color.blue(pixel);              
            }
        }
        int red = (int) (redBucket/pixelCount);
        int green = (int) (greenBucket/pixelCount);
        int blue = (int) (blueBucket/pixelCount);
        View colorView = (View)findViewById(R.id.screen1);
        colorView.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(121,104,88));
    }     
}
```

Now i get the Average skin color by RGB pixel value ... Still i not matching with the source image.i got the Average color of face  is totally different.

Average RGB color Apply into view and compare the source image face and Average RGB color its different one.please any one help me.it would be really help for me.
Any idea about my issue...
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the [Palette library](https://chris.banes.me/2014/10/20/palette-v21/), and might use the vibrant color, or try different combinations

Example snippet:

```
// Synchronous methods.
// --------------------------------
// These should be used when you have access to the underlying image loading     thread.
// Picasso allows this through a Transformation. For other libraries, YMMV.

// Uses the default palette size (16).
Palette p = Palette.generate(bitmap);

// Allows you to specify the maximum palette size, in this case 24.
Palette p = Palette.generate(bitmap, 24);


// Asynchronous methods
// --------------------------------
// This is the quick and easy integration path. Internally uses an AsyncTask so 
// this may not be optimal (since you're dipping in and out of threads)

// Uses the default palette size (16).
Palette.generateAsync(bitmap, new Palette.PaletteAsyncListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGenerated(Palette palette) {
       // Here's your generated palette
    }
});

// Allows you to specify the maximum palette size, in this case 24.
Palette.generateAsync(bitmap, 24, new Palette.PaletteAsyncListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGenerated(Palette palette) {
       // Here's your generated palette
    }
});
```

When a palette is generated, it tries to pick six swatches which match certain criteria:

```
Vibrant. Palette.getVibrantSwatch()
Vibrant dark. Palette.getDarkVibrantSwatch()
Vibrant light. Palette.getLightVibrantSwatch()
Muted. Palette.getMutedSwatch()
Muted dark. Palette.getDarkMutedSwatch()
Muted light. Palette.getLightMutedSwatch()
```